# Can't create LVM on RAID1

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, raid, lvm, mdadm

I have issue creating LVM on RAID1. I have formatted two HDDs for Linux RAID

```
Disk /dev/sdg: 9.1 TiB, 10000831348736 bytes, 19532873728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0EDBEA0C-4245-4BCF-987E-0EAEA8A7BF45

Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdg1   2048 19532869631 19532867584  9.1T Linux RAID

Disk /dev/sdh: 9.1 TiB, 10000831348736 bytes, 19532873728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: EBF194AB-95DD-4924-A85A-789101E1526E

Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdh1   2048 19532869631 19532867584  9.1T Linux RAID
```

And created RAID1 with command

> mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=mirror --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdg1 /dev/sdh1

After that, I tried to create LVM, but I can't pass `pvcreate /dev/md0`. I get error:

```
/dev/md0: pe_align (2048 sectors) must not be less than pe_align_offset (8388607 sectors)
Format-specific initialisation of physical volume /dev/md0 failed.
Failed to setup physical volume "/dev/md0"
```

Also I have tried `vgcreate vg0 /dev/md0` and it successfully created volume group.

How to initialize RAID device to be used for LVM?
Why I can create volume group without initializing physical device?
Is it OK to create volume group without initializing physical device?